# Edit a power point file using iframe on an app

Tags: iframe, powerpoint

I need to embed a powerpoint and make it editable using iframe on an app. I was able to add the view-only version to the app using iframe, but I need users to be able to edit it directly on the app, without having to click and edit it on Microsoft's site.
Is this possible?

I've tried changing the share > embed code Microsoft offers and changing the action on the URL from view to edit, but it didn't work.

This is the embed code Microsoft Online shares:

```
<iframe src="https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx/xxxx/xx/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc={xxxxxxx}&amp;action=embedview&amp;wdAr=1.3333333333333333" width="476px" height="288px" frameborder="0">
This is an embedded 
<a target="_blank" href="https://office.com">Microsoft Office</a> presentation, powered by 
<a target="_blank" href="https://office.com/webapps">Office</a>.
</iframe>
```